# No show keyboard in dialog on Android

Tags: android

I have a activiy and I show a dialog on it when click button. But keyboard not show in dialog. this code of me:

```
final DialogComfigPass comfigPass = new DialogComfigPass(ActivityTable.this);
comfigPass. getWindow (). clearFlags ( WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM );
comfigPass.show();`
```

Comment: add `comfigPass.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`

Comment: put `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`

Comment: Why did you rollback the edits? Your original posting is almost illegible.

Comment: @Henry I guess he is new in here

Comment: post your complete code

Answer (score 1):

**You have to open keyboard in dialog like this **

```
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);‌​`

```
  // Show the keyboard when the dialog is displayed on the screen.
comfigPass.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);‌​
```

before

```
comfigPass.show();
```

**Finally**

```
final DialogComfigPass comfigPass = new DialogComfigPass(ActivityTable.this);
comfigPass. getWindow (). clearFlags ( WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM );
comfigPass.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);‌​
comfigPass.show();`
```

Comment: set `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE`

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work :) `comfigPass.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);‌​`

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.